# Emacs' CopyWithoutSelectAction EditWithoutSelection

Tags: package

The Intellij's [emacsIDEAs plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7163-emacsideas) say,

> *Porting* some great extensions of emacs to Intellij IDEA. such as AceJump, **CopyWithoutSelectAction**. And new created **EditWithoutSelection** (Cut/Move/Replace without selection).

Those shortcuts looks cool, but I'm unable to find such scripts for emacs.

Anybody know where I setup my emacs to behave like Intellij's [emacsIDEAs plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7163-emacsideas)?

UPDATE:

I googled for CopyWithoutSelectAction, or EditWithoutSelection before asking here, but didn't find much good hits. and here is what I get when I do `M-x list-packages` and search for them:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `M-x list-packages` or google for AceJump, CopyWithoutSelectAction, or EditWithoutSelection. They are from user-offered packages, not from vanilla Emacs.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the author of that plugin what he is referring to.